# Adding peers on a live private node

Tags: node, private-mode

Is there any way to add new peers to a running tezos-node in private mode?

Answer (score 1):

Generally we can use the `tezos-admin-client` binary to add new peers:

```
./tezos-admin-client connect address <node ip>:9732
```

But the latest version of the binaries as of today (7/3/2019), the above does not work for nodes in private mode.

Another approach is by calling the `/network/points/{point}/trust` rpc route, example:

```
> curl http://localhost:8732/network/points/<node ip>:9732/trust
{}

// logs in the node
Jun 12 01:48:54 - validator.peer_6: Worker started for NetXgtSLGNJvN:idsMbqZqhyVU
```

Comment: An gitlab issue has created on the issue mentioned above: https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/547

Answer (score 0):

First trust the node, then connect to it:

```
  tezos-admin-client -A localhost trust address <node ip>:9732
  tezos-admin-client -A localhost connect address <node ip>:9732
```